# Jquery UI drag-n-drop with ng-repeat, ng-bind-html and a scope variable

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, ng-bind-html

Good Afternoon :)

**TL;DR** - how do I render a multiple `<div>`s from a `$scoped` JSON blob using `ng-bind-html` inside of a `ng-repeat` where the resulting divs are able to be dragged using JQuery UI's drag logic?

***BACKGROUND***

I am trying to build a website that has a JSON blob (representing the current state of the page). Wherein the page consists of "cards" inside of larger "notebooks" along the lines of:

**JSON**

```
{
"page": {
    "notebookA": [{
        "name": "card1",
        "cardType": "operation",
        "html": "<div draggable>I can be dragged - card1</div>"
    }, {
        "name": "card2",
        "cardType": "selection",
        "html": "<div draggable>I can be dragged - card2</div>"
    }],
    "notebookB": [{
        "name": "card3",
        "cardType": "operation",
        "html": "<div draggable>I can be dragged - card3</div>"
    }, {
        "name": "card4",
        "cardType": "selection",
        "html": "<div draggable>I can be dragged - card4</div>"
    }]
}
```

}

The reason that I want to use a system like this is because I want the ability to save the page JSON to a DB and allow the user to have multiple pages that they can configure then quickly access/use. Rendering based on the $scope.page variable would make life easy.

I am thinking about using Angular to display a real time representation of the page json where the cards are displayed through the use of a $scope.page variable. This means using ng-repeat inside of the notebook divs:

**HTML**

`<div ng-repeat="card in page['notebookA']">
    <div ng-bind-html="card['html']"></div>
</div>`

I am able to get the html to render properly through the use of `html = $sce.trustAsHtml(...)` However I am not able to drag the rendered div.

**JQuery**

```
$(function(){
    $("[draggable]").draggable();
    $('[droppable]').droppable({ drop: Drop });

    function Drop(event, ui) {
        ...
    });
})
```

So I was looking into using a [directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) but was not sure exactly how to approach this type of problem since I believe all I need to do is run `$("[draggable]").draggable();` after rendering the new `<div>`.

***QUESTION***

I've looked through other Stack Overflow questions and was lead in the directive/sce direction but I was not able to find a answer that combined all of the things that I am trying to do. Any help is greatly appreciated!

1. Is this the most effective way to approach this problem or is using innerHTML injection and a "card-render" function a better solution?
2. How would I go about this solution from the point I'm at (Getting the drag to work for the divs created using `ng-bind-html`).